# Spring Boot Websocket Chat and RabbitMQ

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-websocket

I am quite new to Websocket Technology. I am building an application that requires realtime users communication. The messages (chat data) is going to be persisted into Cassandra (NoSql DB). The application is going to have at least 800 users online at any given moment. The communications between users need to be superfast. Persisting data into a DB takes some seconds (nano, micro or whatever).

I was thinking that maybe it would be best if I push all the messages to be persisted into a Message Queue, which will consumed by RabbitMQ consumer whose main job is to save messages into the DB.

I am still a junior developer. Will be extremely grateful for any suggestion. Thanks.